Typesetting This Hebrew Letter with Punctuation
I am trying to typeset this Hebrew word using cjhebrew:

Thank to this helpful document: https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-3/tb44haralambous-hebrew.pdf, I should be able to get all of the letters with the exception of the first letter (with the double dots) on the far left.
It seems not to be in use too often (at least from the various documents I have checked whilst looking for help.)
How may the letter on the far left be typeset with the cjhebrew package?
Also, if someone would tell me the name of this letter, I would appreciate it, for it appears to resemble another Hebrew letter on p. 14 of the above document.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

Some (possibilities) for the letter in question: \, \cjhebrew{r d k}
\end{document}

Output:


ב ׃‎ U+05C3   see  cantillation marks  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_cantillation.  Use a unicode LaTeX engine, preferbly LuaLaTeX  a hebrew font that has the symbols. You can look at the alphabet etc in wikipedia. The paper you linked to is excellent, but outdated to be useful.

@yannisl Many thanks for this information.

It looks like the final form of the letter kaf (using a not too good font that is not showing the proper descenders.
With cjhebrew you would write \<hm*lk:>.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge

\centering\cjhebrew{\<hm*lk:>}

\end{document}


Sincerely, Christian.
